# Mouse leave not firing (nested)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

Why is the mouse leave not firing.

```
$('.tlcr').hide();

$('.tli')
  .on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      $('.tlcr').hide();
      const index = $(this).index('.tli');
      $('.tlcr').eq(index).show();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $('.tlcr').eq(index)
        .on({
          mouseenter: function() {
            $('.tlcr').eq(index).show();
          }, mouseleave: function() {
                $('.tlcr').hide();    
          }
        });
      $('.tlcr').hide();
    }
  });
```

Above code into a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/czqab09j/3/

I want to achieve this: https://jsfiddle.net/aLquks1c/1/

But I would like to achieve it with the code from the first fiddle. But I am doing something wrong.

Comment: index isn't defined

Comment: @JayB You are probably right. I modified it a bit and it is now working.

Comment: You should probably remove it since it was just an undefined variable and wouldn't be helpful to others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working and here is the updated code:

```
$('.tli')
  .on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      $('.tlcr').hide();
      const index = $(this).index('.tli');
      $('.tlcr').eq(index).show();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $('.tlcr').eq(index)
        .on({
          mouseenter: function() {
            $('.tlcr').eq(index).show();
          }
        });
    }
  });
  $('.tlcr')
    .on({
      mouseleave: function() {
        $('.tlcr').hide();
      }
    });
```

I basically removed the nested mouse leave function and made it standalone.

See here the result in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/czqab09j/4/